# resolve() for django url test doesn't work

Tags: python, django, tdd

I had a test for url resolver but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]
```

blog/test.py

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from django.test import TestCase
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from .views import post_list, post_new
class PostNewTest(TestCase):
    def test_root_url_resolve_to_post_list_view(self):
        found = resolve('post/new')
        self.assertEqual(found.func, post_new)
```

But test fails :

```
(tdd_djangogirls) Chois@Chois-MacPro tdd_djangogirls $./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
...E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_root_url_resolve_to_post_list_view (blog.tests.PostNewTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chois/Workspace/django/tdd_djangogirls/blog/tests.py", line 23, in test_root_url_resolve_to_post_list_view
    found = resolve('post/new')
  File "/Users/Chois/.virtualenvs/tdd_djangogirls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 534, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/Users/Chois/.virtualenvs/tdd_djangogirls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 405, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'path': path})
django.core.urlresolvers.Resolver404: {'path': 'post/new'}
```

What's wrong with it?

I also did the test with `found = resolve('/post/new')`, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: What about `/post/new/`, which is what you define the URL as?

Comment: I also did the test with found = resolve('/post/new'), but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Add `/` at the end of the url. Look at Your url regex. You have `/` at the end, but You test without `/`.

Comment: `/post/new` is not the same as `/post/new/`

Comment: Is it same defining url as '/post/new' and '/post/new/' in urls.py?

Comment: No, it isn't. There is an [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#append-slash) setting which makes the core middleware add a slash if it is missing. But this is done in middleware. Your router will treat them as completely different paths.